# CSS Issue in Jsp and HTML

Tags: html, css, spring, jsp, spring-form

I started working in one of the legacy applications and it uses JSP with CSS.

It has a textarea like below which has the CSS but the FONT in the textarea is not on the TOP - LEFT, Rather it is there in middle of the text area like below

JSP Code :

```
<td class="tableContents"><textarea class="headerTextArea" readonly="readonly">
                                                        <c:forEach var="fordisplay"
                                                            items="${listofvalues}" varStatus="idx">
                                                        <c:out value="${fordisplay }" />
                                                        <% out.print("\n"); %>
                                                        </c:forEach>
                                                        </textarea></td>
```

CSS Code :

```
.headerTextArea {overflow: auto;  COLOR: blue; border: outset 1px white;  background: lightgray;  FONT: 10pt 'Arial', 'Sans-serif'; width: 185px; padding-top: 0px;padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;}
```

Inspect view from browser :

[image]

**Expected** :

[image]

**Actual** :

[image]

Could someone help on achieving the actual (having the FONT text in the Top - Left view) ?

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: What is your textarea `line-height`?

Comment: @Jared do I need to set that ?

Comment: Well, i'm not sure, what is the current value? The result you are getting might come from incorrect `line-height` or a `padding-top` or a `display: flex` with an `align-items: center`. Try to check these property or set them to desired values.

Comment: You are printing all of listofvalues values  into one textarea element separated by a newline character. You should print  listofvalues  to see it's contents.   Maybe,  CC is not the first value and there are empty Strings  before it in the list.